# Backing up an SVN repository on Mac OS X

Tags: backup, mac-osx, svn, time-machine, launchd

I am trying to automate backing up an SVN server on my G5 running 10.5 Leopard. I already have Time Machine set up.

I figured it would be best to exclude the SVN repository from Time Machine, and manually make a backup of the repository (perhaps using `tar`) in a directory that Time Machine can see. **Is that necessary, or can I just let Time Machine backup the SVN repository as-is?**

If not, I have already created a set of shell scripts for shutting down `svnserve`, making the tarball, and restarting `svnserve` respectively. I can run all three from the command line just fine. I also recreated a fourth "nightly" script that calls all three in sequence. This also runs fine on the command line. However, I can't seem to get launchd to run the script properly and it's driving me crazy. I can't seem to get `launchd` to start logging anything, and I've followed [Apple's advice](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECLAUNCHD) exactly. **How can I get `launchd` to start logging, and how should I configure a `bash` script to run when called from `launchd`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with time machine to be honest, but I know that just dumping an SVN repository back in place isn't really a restore.

What we do is an SVN DUMP into a folder, and then we added that folder to our backup routine. The SVN DUMP runs about 30 minutes before the nightly backup.